# How to more effectively sort the elements of one list after the corresponding elements in another list?

Tags: python, list

So, what I have are two lists containing data. One has info about the height that an object was dropped from (called heightsTotal), and one has info about the time that it took for that object to drop (called timesTotal). For each height an object was dropped several times. What I want to do is take elements from the list with times and sort them into lists within a list depending upon which height that time corresponds to.

I have solved the problem, but it takes a lot of code. My code looks like:

```
timesAfterHeight = [[], [], [], [], []]

counter = 0
for i in heightsTotal:
    if i == 0.2:
        timesAfterHeight[0].append(timesTotal[counter])
    if i == 0.4:
        timesAfterHeight[1].append(timesTotal[counter])
    if i == 0.6:
        timesAfterHeight[2].append(timesTotal[counter])
    if i == 0.8:
        timesAfterHeight[3].append(timesTotal[counter])
    if i == 1:
        timesAfterHeight[4].append(timesTotal[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Is there a better, more effective way to do this? Thanks so much for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the heights to the indices

```
times = {0.2: 0, 0.4: 1, 0.6: 2, 0.8: 3, 1: 4}

counter = 0
for i in heightsTotal:
    timesAfterHeight[times[i]].append(timesTotal[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the mathematical conventions of the language you're using, I'd probably do something like

```
height = heightsTotal[counter]
index = 5 * height - 1
timesAfterHeight[index].append(timesTotal[counter])
```

Comment: I just needed to convert index from a float to an integer, but otherwise that did the trick!